# How to Get AWS IAM credentials of the ECS Instance its running within - using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm struggling to get a S3Client having the credentials of the ECS Instance its running within.

The ECS instance has policy & trust as below - which I think is okay

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
```

I don't see how to get the client - In the .net world I would use

```
s3Client = Amazon.AWSClientFactor.CreateAmazonS3Client()
```

But I need to do this in Java - I have tried a number of ways but always get 'denied'

```
s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

Can any one point me at the corrects method & documentation?

Comment: Try a single resource: arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*

Comment: that fixed the problem - the puts now work - it was a permission issue.

Comment: I also used   AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance();
  AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).build();

Answer (score 1):

The IAM policy you are using is incorrect, specifically the `resource`. To indicate all objects in myBucket, use the following:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
```